# Implementing multiple custom sorts

Tags: c#, sorting

The following code works, but I'm sure there's a cleaner way to implement it and I'd appreciate any guidance on how to go about that.

I have a class Result which I want to sort sometimes by score (which is just an int) and sometimes by parts which are strings whose first char is a digit in [1,7] and whose second char is one of C, D, H, S, N (which are in alphabetical order except that the N needs to come last).

```
public class Result : IEquatable<Result>, IComparable<Result>
{
    private int score;// Unique NS value for all par contracts.
    private string pars;// All possible pars on this deal.

  // Default comparer for Result type.
    public int CompareTo(Result compareResult)
    {
        // A null value means that this object is greater.
        if (compareResult == null)
            return 1;

        else
            return this.Score.CompareTo(compareResult.Score);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return score;
    }

    public bool Equals(Result other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return (this.Score.Equals(other.Score));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Score: " + Score + "   Par: " + Pars;
    }
};




public class InitArray
{
    public static readonly char[] bridgeChar = new char[Constants.CHAR_MAX];

    static InitArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bridgeChar.Length; i++)
        {
            bridgeChar[i] = Char.ToUpper((char)i);
        }
        //Only concerned with ordering C, D, H, S, N=NT.
        bridgeChar['N'] = bridgeChar['Z'];
    }
};

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Result result = new Result();

    // Create a list of results.
    List<Result> results = new List<Result>();

    // Add results to the list.
    results.Add(new Result() { Score = 110, Pars = "3C" });
    results.Add(new Result() { Score = -200, Pars = "4Hx" });
    results.Add(new Result() { Score = -100, Pars = "3Hx" });
    results.Add(new Result() { Score = -100, Pars = "3Sx" });
    results.Add(new Result() { Score = 400, Pars = "3N" });

    // Sort on the list using the default comparer.

    results.Sort();

    // Sort calling the Sort(Comparison(T) overload using 
    // an anonymous method.
    results.Sort(delegate (Result x, Result y)
    {
        if (x.Score == 0 && y.Score == 0) return 0;
        else if (x.Score == 0) return -1;
        else if (y.Score == 0) return 1;
        else return x.Score.CompareTo(y.Score);
    });

    Console.WriteLine("\nAfter sort by score:");
    foreach (Result aResult in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(aResult);
    }

    // Sort on pars using an anonymous method.
    results.Sort(delegate (Result x, Result y)
    {
        if ((x == null) && (y == null)) return 0;
        else if (x == null) return -1;
        else if (y == null) return 1;
        else
        {// Compare the two strings.
            if (x.Pars[0].CompareTo(y.Pars[0]) == 0)
            {
                // If the strings start with the same character, sort them by Denomination.
                return InitArray.bridgeChar[y.Pars[1]].CompareTo(InitArray.bridgeChar[x.Pars[1]]);
            }
            else
            { // sort them with ordinary string comparison.
                return x.CompareTo(y);
            }
        }
    });

    results.Reverse(); //Need them in ascending order.

    Console.WriteLine("\nAfter sort by denom:");
    foreach (Result aResult in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(aResult);
    }
  }
}
```

Output is as required:

```
After sort by score:
Score: -200   Par: 4Hx
Score: -100   Par: 3Hx
Score: -100   Par: 3Sx
Score: 110   Par: 3C
Score: 400   Par: 3N

After sort by denom:
Score: 110   Par: 3C
Score: -100   Par: 3Hx
Score: -100   Par: 3Sx
Score: 400   Par: 3N
Score: -200   Par: 4Hx
```

Comment: You can use OrderBy instead of Sort.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This code is broken. `Result` does not have a property called `Score`. You've posted edited code :-|

Comment: Nor does it have a property/field `Pars`

Answer (score 2):

Without getting into why you designed your business logic this way (I would've made Pars a separate class or struct, to accommodate the complexity), I guess this is somewhat a decent approach.

By using an `IComparer<T>`, you can implement whatever logic you need, thus separating the concern of sorting Pars into its own place.

I've used a predefined list of characters (in C#, the simplest list of `char` is `string`, but you can use any type that has an `IndexOf` method) in order to have a single, distinct source of truth for the order of the chars that can be easily modified without breaking anything. I've named it `PairOrder` for lack of a better name, feel free to name it whatever you like.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var data = new[] {
      new Result { Score = 110, Pars = "3C" },
      new Result { Score = -200, Pars = "4Hx" },
      new Result { Score = -100, Pars = "3Hx" },
      new Result { Score = -100, Pars = "3Sx" },
      new Result { Score = 400, Pars = "3N" }
    };

    var sortedByScore = data.OrderBy(item => item.Score)
      .ThenBy(item => item.Pars, new ParsComparer());

    Console.WriteLine("Sorting by Score first");
    foreach (var item in sortedByScore)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    var sortedByPars = data.OrderBy(item => item.Pars, new ParsComparer())
      .ThenBy(item => item.Score);

    Console.WriteLine("\nSorting by Pars first");
    foreach (var item in sortedByPars)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
  }
}

public class Result
{
  public int Score { get; set; }
  public string Pars { get; set; }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return string.Format("Score: {0}; Pars: {1}", Score, Pars);
  }
}

public class ParsComparer : IComparer<string>
{
  private string ParsOrder = "CDHSN";

  public int Compare(string a, string b)
  {
    var delta = a[0].CompareTo(b[0]);

    if (delta == 0)
    {
      var indexA = ParsOrder.IndexOf(a[1]);
      var indexB = ParsOrder.IndexOf(b[1]);

      delta = indexA.CompareTo(indexB);
    }

    return delta;
  }
}
```

The output is what you expected:

```
Sorting by Score first
Score: -200; Pars: 4Hx
Score: -100; Pars: 3Hx
Score: -100; Pars: 3Sx
Score: 110; Pars: 3C
Score: 400; Pars: 3N

Sorting by Pars first
Score: 110; Pars: 3C
Score: -100; Pars: 3Hx
Score: -100; Pars: 3Sx
Score: 400; Pars: 3N
Score: -200; Pars: 4Hx
```

**Disclaimer:** it's been a while since I've written any significant C# code. There are probably better ways to write and organize this code.

I also don't make any promises regarding performance. I don't think you'll have any issues, but the `IndexOf` lookup might introduce a bottleneck, specially if the list of chars gets too big.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rafael.  Performance in this section isn't going to be an issue - it's all driven by a 3rd party DLL which, at best, will take 30secs to answer each call!!!  Re business logic, I'm between stools, I have working C++ custom code that I'm rewriting in C# to interface to a SQL DB.  So, result.par will become a foreign key to a separate table.  But the question of how best in general to implement multiple custom sorts caught my interest.

Comment: In that case, I believe chaining `.OrderBy()` and `ThenBy()` using an `IComparer<T>`, like I did, is going to be your best bet. At most, you could encapsulate that into extension methods for `IEnumerable<Result>` if you end up using the same logic over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want different comparisons, use different comparers for `Result`.

This does require `Result` to have a properties that are accessible - either public or internal and in the same assembly as the comparer.

```
public class ResultScoreComparer : IComparer<Result>
{
    public int Compare(Result x, Result y)
    {
        return (x?.Score ?? int.MinValue).CompareTo(y?.Score ?? int.MinValue);
    }
}

public class BridgeCharactersComparer : IComparer<Result>
{
    public int Compare(Result x, Result y)
    {
        //whatever the other comparison is.
    }
}
```

Now the only thing that changes when sorting is which comparer you use.

```
var sorted = results.OrderBy(result => result, comparer);
```